# How to practice different dynamics in each hand

Tags: piano, dynamics

In the piece "[Melody](http://imslp.org/wiki/Album_f%C3%BCr_die_Jugend,_Op.68_%28Schumann,_Robert%29)" from Op. 68 (Schumann) the right hand plays piano while the left hand plays pianissimo. I find it difficult to play different dynamics in different hands.

How should I practice different dynamics in each hand, starting small?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48/playing-one-hand-loudly-and-the-other-quietly